# Is there a simple way to measure total memory consumption?

Tags: rust, heap-memory

I want to report the total memory usage of an Actix Web application from within itself.
Because this is only shown at the bottom of a single page and used very rarely and it does not need to be that accurate (e.g. it is enough if it measures just the heap), I don't want to dedicate too much code to it or use an external crate.

Is there a simple one-liner to measure how much total memory my program is using without using an external dependency or is that not possible?

Comment: On linux you cold get the info from `/proc/self/maps` but you'd have to parse it.

Comment: Or from [`/proc/self/statm`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#id9) which should be easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple one-liner in Rust

No.

The best way to get the total memory consumption of a process is via the OS's facilities. Which, of course, depends on what OS you are running on.

There's crates like [sysinfo](https://lib.rs/crates/sysinfo) that abstract it all away though and implement cross-platform process metrics.

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/memory-stats seems to be the simplest one.